# program isn't printing my long long variable

Tags: c, variables, printf, format-specifiers

I am attempting to solve, using C, question 3 on Project Euler.
I am having trouble with the large integer that is in the question - int and long got me an "overflow" warning, and my program didn't print the result to the console. So I switched to a 'long long' type, the warning is gone but the console still isn't printing the answer, which makes me think I have a mistake in my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
long long largest=0;
long long div=2;
long long i = 600851475143;

while(div<i)
{
    if(i%div == 0)
    {
    largest=div;
    }
    div++;
}
printf("%I64d\n", largest);
return 0;
}
```

I am using Mingw as a compiler for this, on Windows 7.

Comment: Is it not printing anything, or the wrong thing, and if the latter, what should it print and what is it printing?

Comment: Have you tried using doubles instead?

Comment: That doesn't have anything to do with your compiler (GCC is a "freestanding implementation", which means (roughly) that it comes without a standard library) but with your `libc` (the standard library), where `printf` is defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is OK..Its just that it is taking too long to run.The following code prints out the steps.

```
while(div<i)
{
  printf("%lld\n",div);
  if(i%div == 0)
  {
  largest=div;
  }
  div+=1;
}
```

As per algorithm point  i would recommend you to initialize `div = 600851475143/2` and count backwards

Answer (score 1):

Use `%lld` to print `long long int` type data.

```
printf("%lld\n", largest)
```

or change `I` in your format specifier to `l`.

Comment: mingw will link to the win32 runtime/SDK, which will happily accept %I64d, only newer versions of the SDK knows about %lld

Comment: @nos; See carefully, OP hasn't used `l` instead he used `I`.

Comment: @haacks Yes, `%I64d` is correct for win32. The op counts to 600851475143, which is going to take _quite_ a while, so the problem is likely that his loop doesn't terminate.

Answer (score 0):

Try `%ll` and it will work fine

```
printf("%ll\n", largest);
```

Answer (score 0):

please use `%lld` as format specifier. for more information refer [link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19205-01/819-5265/bjabu/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
long long largest=0;
long long div=2;
long long i = 600851475143;

while(div<i)
{
    if(i%div == 0)
    {
         largest=div;
         break;//out of loop
         printf("%lld\n", largest);//or add this ,I don't think so
    }
    div++;
}
printf("%lld\n", largest);
return 0;
}
```

maybe that's what you want,maybe not...